# Lazy Evaluation when Multiplying with Zero

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation

With the program below,

```
f 0 0 0 1 = 0
f 0 0 1 0 = f 0 0 0 1 + 1
f 0 1 0 0 = f 0 0 1 1 + 1
f 1 0 0 0 = f 0 1 1 1 + 1
f a b c d = (p + q + r + s) / (a + b + c + d)
    where
    p
        | a > 0 = a * f (a - 1) (b + 1) (c + 1) (d + 1)
        | otherwise = 0
    q
        | b > 0 = b * f a (b - 1) (c + 1) (d + 1)
        | otherwise = 0
    r
        | c > 0 = c * f a b (c - 1) (d + 1)
        | otherwise = 0
    s
        | d > 0 = d * f a b c (d - 1)
        | otherwise = 0

main = print (f 1 1 1 1)
```

I thought it can be simplified as,

```
f 0 0 0 1 = 0
f 0 0 1 0 = f 0 0 0 1 + 1
f 0 1 0 0 = f 0 0 1 1 + 1
f 1 0 0 0 = f 0 1 1 1 + 1
f a b c d = (p + q + r + s) / (a + b + c + d)
    where
    p = a * f (a - 1) (b + 1) (c + 1) (d + 1)
    q = b * f a (b - 1) (c + 1) (d + 1)
    r = c * f a b (c - 1) (d + 1)
    s = d * f a b c (d - 1)

main = print (f 1 1 1 1)
```

because besides both being mathematically sound, I thought that with lazy evaluation, the compiler or interpreter should be able to decide that multiplying anything to 0 is needless. But well, the program did go into infinite loop. Why so?

Comment: @Carsten Well because multiplying anything to 0 is unnecessary mathematically. Perhaps I believed the Haskell compiler too much?

Comment: BTW: I think you would change the function anyway for example `f 0 0 0 (-1)` will go into an infinte loop after your transformation

Comment: @CarstenKönig there are inbuilt rules that will avoid multiplication by a constant 0.  The argument is still evaluated, it's only the multiplication that isn't performed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Built-in multiplication is strict in both arguments -- that is, it evaluates both arguments -- regardless of whether one of them is zero, which is what is causing your program to loop.  You could define your own multiplication operator which lazily eliminates one or the other of the arguments:

```
0 .* y = 0
x .* y = x * y
```

or the other way around.  It takes a bit more to define an operator which eliminates zero on both sides, but it can be done with the [`unamb`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.5/docs/Data-Unamb.html) package:

```
x .* y = unambs [ assuming (x == 0) 0
                , assuming (y == 0) 0
                , x * y
                ]
```

Though, as far as I know, this does not yet have a sufficiently reliable implementation :-/.

Answer (score 4):

As well as defining your own multiplication operator as @luqui suggests, you can define your own type whose built-in multiplication short-circuits:

```
newtype SCZero a = SCZero a
    deriving Eq

instance Show a => Show (SCZero a) where
    show (SCZero x) = show x

instance (Eq a, Num a) => Num (SCZero a) where
    SCZero x + SCZero y = SCZero (x + y)
    SCZero 0 * SCZero y = SCZero 0
    SCZero x * SCZero y = SCZero (x * y)
    abs (SCZero x) = SCZero (abs x)
    signum (SCZero x) = SCZero (signum x)
    fromInteger x = SCZero (fromInteger x)
    negate (SCZero x) = SCZero (negate x)

instance (Eq a, Fractional a) => Fractional (SCZero a) where
    fromRational x = SCZero (fromRational x)
    SCZero 0 / SCZero y = SCZero 0
    SCZero x / SCZero y = SCZero (x / y)
```

You can then use your existing code directly, by just specifying the result type to be a `SCZero`:

```
*Main> print (f 1 1 1 1 :: SCZero Double)
0.464398781601087
```